# Meteor removing document by ID error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to remove a single document by its id and I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: object is not a function
I20160208-21:03:51.816(-8)?at packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:322:1
I20160208-21:03:51.816(-8)?at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
```

I have a form that users fill out, and when submitted, the document ID is returned and stored as a session variable `curID` (some other session variables are set as well but irrelevant for this)

On a separate page, there is a delete button. When clicked, it will bring up a confirm box, and if OK, then a meteor method is called to remove the document from the collection. the `curID` session variable is passed so the method knows which document to remove

This is the code that handles the delete button click:

```
"submit .delete-participant": function(event){
      // Prevent default browser form submit
      event.preventDefault();

      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this participant?")){
        Meteor.call("deleteParticipant", Session.get("curID"), function(err, id){
          if (err){
            alert(err);
          } else {
            Session.set("curID", "");
            Session.set("participantCreated", false);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

The `deleteParticipant` method just finds the 1 document with a matching ID (from the `curSub` session variable) and removes it:

```
Meteor.methods({
  deleteParticipant: function(id){
    Participants.remove({_id: id}, {justOne: true})
  }
});
```

I'm probably overlooking something very basic here but I'm not sure which object the error is referring to...

Comment: Check the type of `id` on server.

Comment: i find 3 issues here that may cause the problem, `1.` whenever server doesn't have any `return`, client side callback will have only one parameter `error`.
`2.`if you remove by `_id` , it means you're removing only one item, you don't need to write `justOne:true`.
`3.`. most importantly before removing object, `console.log` in the server that whether your `id` is being passed correctly or not.

Comment: I've never seen the `justOne` parameter used in Meteor. It doesn't show up in the docs. As @FaysalAhmed says, you don't need it anyway.

Comment: Turns out the `justOne` was causing the problem. I removed that and things seem to be working OK now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, taking it justOne or simply ",1" also solved my issue.